# Ransack gem not querying results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I can't figure out why the search produces no results. Sometimes it gives partial results from the verified and accetpes_bitcoin checkboxes

I have read through the documentation, I can't find the solution

My search form:

```
 <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :business_name_cont%>
    <%= f.collection_select :categories_id_eq, Category.all, :id, :name, include_blank: "Select Category" %>
    <%=f.select :addresses_country_cont,Address.all.map{|n|n.country}, include_blank: "Select Country"%>
    <%= f.check_box :verified_true %>
    <%= f.check_box :accepts_bitcoin_true %>
    <%=f.submit"%>
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
......
 def index
  @q = Business.ransack(params[:q])
  @businesses = @q.result.includes(:addresses)
....
```

The `business_name_cont` produces no results.

I noticed the form queries only one record out of the 100 seeded data I have,

Model:

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
.......
has_many :addresses, inverse_of: :business ,dependent: :destroy
......


class Address < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :business
   validate :country, :phone :street ... etc
......
```

Search params when only verified checkbox is selected:

```
Started GET "/businesses?q%5Bbusiness_name_cont%5D=&q%5Bcategories_id_eq%5D=&q%5Baddresses_country_cont%5D=&q%5Bverified_true%5D=0&q%5Bverified_true%5D=1&q%5Baccepts_partnership_true%5D=0&commit=Search+Business" for ::1 at 2021-04-09 22:00:51 +0100
Processing by BusinessesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"business_name_cont"=>"", "categories_id_eq"=>"", "addresses_country_cont"=>"", "verified_true"=>"1", "accepts_partnership_true"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Search Business"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering businesses/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Category Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" ORDER BY name
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:7
   (2.1ms)  SELECT "addresses"."country" FROM "addresses" ORDER BY country
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:8
  Business Load (3.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" WHERE ("businesses"."verified" = TRUE AND "businesses"."accepts_partnership" != TRUE) ORDER BY "businesses"."point" DESC
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:46
  Address Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1  [["business_id", 27]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:46
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 27], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 27], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 27], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 59)
  Business Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" WHERE "businesses"."accepts_partnership" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["accepts_partnership", true], ["LIMIT", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:100
  Rendered businesses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 46.4ms | Allocations: 11231)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_logo.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 38)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 285)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 67.3ms | Allocations: 16110)
Completed 200 OK in 71ms (Views: 49.7ms | ActiveRecord: 18.5ms | Allocations: 16999)
```

i have 5 verified businesses but only 1 shows up

#### search params when only accepts_partnership checkbox is selected

```
    Started GET "/businesses?q%5Bbusiness_name_cont%5D=&q%5Bcategories_id_eq%5D=&q%5Baddresses_country_cont%5D=&q%5Bverified_true%5D=0&q%5Baccepts_partnership_true%5D=0&q%5Baccepts_partnership_true%5D=1&commit=Search+Business" for ::1 at 2021-04-09 22:06:37 +0100
Processing by BusinessesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"business_name_cont"=>"", "categories_id_eq"=>"", "addresses_country_cont"=>"", "verified_true"=>"0", "accepts_partnership_true"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Search Business"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering businesses/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Category Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" ORDER BY name
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:7
   (2.2ms)  SELECT "addresses"."country" FROM "addresses" ORDER BY country
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:8
  Business Load (4.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" WHERE ("businesses"."verified" != TRUE AND "businesses"."accepts_partnership" = TRUE) ORDER BY "businesses"."point" DESC
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:46
  Address Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13)  [[nil, 5], [nil, 9], [nil, 10], [nil, 12], [nil, 14], [nil, 15], [nil, 17], [nil, 20], [nil, 21], [nil, 22], [nil, 24], [nil, 31], [nil, 35]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:46
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 5], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 59)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 9], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 55)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 10], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 54)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 12], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 23], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 14], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 27], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 57)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 15], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 29], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 55)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 17], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 57)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 20], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 39], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 21], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 41], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 22], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 43], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 24], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 47], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 24], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 24], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 56)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 31], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 61], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 31], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 31], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 55)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 35], ["record_type", "Business"], ["name", "logo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 69], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:56
  Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "business_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "business_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business_categories"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 35], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:62
  Address Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."business_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["business_id", 35], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:69
  Rendered businesses/business_card/_card_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 55)
  Business Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" WHERE "businesses"."accepts_partnership" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["accepts_partnership", true], ["LIMIT", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:100
  Rendered businesses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 204.2ms | Allocations: 63445)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_logo.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 38)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 282)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 211.0ms | Allocations: 68316)
Completed 200 OK in 214ms (Views: 137.9ms | ActiveRecord: 73.7ms | Allocations: 69201)
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your params so that we can see what is actually being sent to the controller. The query that is being executed would also be useful (should show up in the development logs)

Comment: I have added the params results

Comment: Can you post the actual query that runs? It seems possible that the 3 that don't show up are because they are verified and the params are only looking for unverified?

Comment: i added the full query

Comment: @foliwe83 "I have 5 verified businesses but only 1 shows up". Looks like only of them have `verified ` set to true and `accepts_partnership` set to false.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan, Thanks I did't realised all the fields need to match. It was working correctly. . That is good news. How do i bypass the check boxes from the search. For example. I want all categories to be index if the business is  verified or not or accepting_partnership or not?

Comment: @foliwe83 Do you mean you want to ignore `verified` and `accepts_partnership` params if they are "0"?

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan yes

Comment: @foliwe83 One way to do it would be to create an array of keys you want to check and use [`ActionController::Parameters#delete_if`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-delete_if) to delete the entries if the key is present in the `keys` array and the value is `'0'` - `keys = ['verified', 'accepts_partnership']; params[:q].delete_if {|k, v| keys.include?(k) && v == '0' }`.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan. this a new to me. So I guess the code goes into the index action of the business controller?

Comment: @foliwe83 You could add it to the `index` method or add it to a `private` method `sanitized_params` (for example) and call it inside the `index` method - `@q = Business.ransack(sanitized_params)`

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan I have created a private method called sanitize_params then call it inside the index method.  I don't know if this is what you meant. if yes , i have an error ``undefined method `delete_if' for nil:NilClass``

Comment: Looks like `params[:q]` is `nil`. Can you check the logs?

Comment: undefined method ``delete_if``